# push key and values pair in object using loop in Javascipt

Tags: javascript, object

Hi I'm a beginner in javascript and trying to create a function that gets two objects as an argument, and in function, I want to create a new object which has keys of second object and value from the first object and if there's an extra key comes then will print same as it is in my created object

**Output should be**
{
Actor: "Programmer",
firstName: "Bobo",
shoeSize: 100
}

```
const obj = { 
  name: 'Bobo', 
  job: 'Programmer', 
  shoeSize: 100 
};

const obj2 = { 
  name: 'firstName', 
  job: 'Actor' 
}

function joinArray(data, data2){
  var a={};

  for(var key in data){
    if(key in data2){
      a{data2.key} = data{key}
    } else {
      a{data2.key} = data{key}
    }
  }

  return a
}

console.log(joinArray(obj, obj2))
```

Comment: the correct syntax to access/assign object properties is using `[]` instead of `{}` (as in your example) `a[data2[key]] = data[key]`

Comment: Also, arrays and objects are different things. Arrays are sequential buckets accessed by integers 0, 1, 2,... while objects are key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

```
const obj = { 
  name: 'Bobo', 
  job: 'Programmer', 
  shoeSize: 100 
};

const obj2 = { 
  name: 'firstName', 
  job: 'Actor' 
}

function joinArray(data, data2) {
  var a={};

  for(var key in data) {
    if(key in data2) {
      a[data2[key]] = data[key]
    } else {
      a[key] = data[key]
    }
  }

  return a
}

console.log(joinArray(obj, obj2))
```

This is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/q4g8dpbm/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that

```js
const  obj = { name: 'Bobo', job: 'Programmer', shoeSize: 100 } 
const obj2 = { name: 'firstName', job: 'Actor' } 

function joinArray( data, keyNames)
  {
  let rep = {}
  for (let k in data)
    rep[((keyNames[k]) ? keyNames[k] : k)] = data[k]
  return rep  
  }

console.log( joinArray(obj,obj2) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```

OR:

```js
const  obj = { name: 'Bobo', job: 'Programmer', shoeSize: 100 } 
const obj2 = { name: 'firstName', job: 'Actor' } 

const joinArray = (data, keyNames) => 
  Object.keys(data ).reduce((rep,k) =>
  {
  rep[((keyNames[k]) ? keyNames[k] : k)] = data[k]
  return rep  
  },{}) 
 
console.log( joinArray(obj,obj2) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```